# What means W(-k) from sympy solve result?

Tags: sympy

I was using sympy to find roots of the function x+k*exp(-x)
My Python code is the following :

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
init_session()
k=symbols('k',real=True,nonzero=True)
f=Function('f')
f=x+k*E**(-x)

solve(f,x)
```

The result of the solve command is [W(-k)]
Can you explain to me the signification of this result?

Comment: W(z) is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: Also note that `f = Function('f')` has no effect in your code. The variable `f` gets erased and assigned a new value in the next line.